# How to include special characters in a pebble font?

Tags: c, truetype, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

When pebble cloud imports a font resource, it gives the option to use a regular expression to specify the characters to import.

It does not seem to recognize the characters that I'm trying to import.
when I use [01¬•⚫○☯]
I get the zero and the 1, but not the not sign or anything else.

When I import without specifications it just gets the standard alpha numeric.

I would be happy if I could get at least the not sign and the bullet.

Comment: Have you tried unicode directly? `01^\U20AC` should import an euro sign. Not all symbols will be supported but it is fullwidth, that is `\U0001F603` should result in a smiley, pardon, emoji if supported.

Comment: The code may work but those characters could not be present in the font. Check that first.